# Knockout.js: what is the difference between ko.mapping and ko.observable ?

Tags: knockout.js

I know that both of them are used for data binding. Still, when do we have to use ko.mapping.fromJS(...) and when ko.observable(...) ? What is the difference between the two ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In some projects, sometimes the data object you get back from the server is complex, with lots of properties, which in turn have more properties. You may wish to make all, or a significant number of them observable, so that the UI is reactive to changes. It's a tedious job to manually create all those observables and assign the values.

The mapping plugin allows you to automatically generate observables for the properties of the data object. There are various customisations that you can do with the plugin, such as ignoring certain properties, or choosing which properties not to become observable vs just normal properties.

**The main point here is that the underlying behaviour is exactly the same.** It's all observables, just created in a different way. See [Mapping](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html) for the Knockout documentation with examples.

Personally, I've not used the mapping plugin before. I've never really found a need for it. The application I work on is 
componentized, which means for any given component, there isn't going to be a huge amount of data returned from the server/data source. Secondly, of that data that is used, only a handful of properties need to be made observable.

Comment: So what I understand, it that ko.mapping is effective in cases of nested JSONs, where you want all levels of object to be observed. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, just for more complex structures, where it would be tedious job to manually create properties on your vm for each object property.